# Asynchronous programming in ADO.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, asynchronous

The following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx explains the new asynchronous programming features with the 4.5 .Net framework, which for the most part is fairly straight forward reading.

However, I just want to make sure of something....

If I am using a SQLDataReader in a **web service** and I create a service reference on the client to use that web service by generating asynchronous methods in the proxy (via the service reference dialog options), I very well imagine I **wouldn't** need to use the methodologies mentioned in the link above.

Rather, I would use the **async, Task, and await** keywords **on the client appropriately when calling that web service method**

Since checking those options on the Web Service dialog, it will automatically create asynchronous method calls for the ADO.Net call.

So, if you have a method called *GetCategories* in the web service, it will automatically create an asynchronous call called *GetCategoriesAsync* in the web service which could be called from the client. Again, no need to place the asynchronous attributes **on the web service method call**; only for an ADO.Net call which is **not** using a web service or one which is using a web service, but does **not** have the asynchronous options checked.

Am I correct in my thinking?

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what you want to make asynchronous.

Network communications are inherently asynchronous. When Visual Studio creates a client proxy for your web service, it creates both asynchronous and synchronous methods (where the synchronous methods just block waiting for a response). So, your web client can be asynchronous, and this is true regardless of how the server is implemented. In other words, a server can be synchronous or asynchronous, and a client can be synchronous or asynchronous, completely independent from each other.

On the client side, you should almost always use asynchronous methods on the proxy. The primary benefit on the client is responsiveness.

On the server side, you can get a scalability benefit by using an asynchronous implementation. However, if your backend is a single SQL server database, and every request hits that database, then there usually isn't a benefit from making your web service asynchronous. This is because (in that case) the scalability bottleneck is the SQL server, not the web server. OTOH, if your backend is a SQL server *cluster* or Azure SQL, then you can get a scalability benefit by using an asynchronous web service implementation.

The old-style common scenario was `client <-> API <-> DB`, and in that architecture there's [no real need for asynchronous DB access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/11/14/should-my-database-calls-be-asynchronous.aspx). However, more and more architectures are looking like `client <-> API <-> cloud storage / APIs`, and that's when `async` really brings benefits to the API layer.

Comment: Stephen, thanks for your comment, but I was wondering if you could be more direct in an answer in this particular scenario. Based on what I know, if I use the async, Task, and await keywords on the client call to the method in the web service, there wouldn't be a need for me to actually code any asynchronous functionality on the web service side. If an asynchronous web service implementation is used, would I still need to call that web service implementation asynchronously from the client?

Comment: Stephen, fyi, in my particular case, I have multiple DB calls to make in parallel. So, do I still need to make the web service side with the SQLDataReader and asynchronous method or can I call it from the client asynchronously from the generated proxy code with their corresponding Async methods.

Comment: Note that in the article (Creating an Asynchronous Gizmos Action Method) of the link you provided, the Service Reference ( via the proxy) automatically created a corresponding Asynchronous method. Based on that, there shouldn't be a need for me to manually create another asynchronous method in the web service. I can simply "wrap it up" in the async, Task, and await keywords.

Comment: After reading the articles, it appears that I'm able to stick to my original plan. Since the service will automatically create a corresponding asynchronous method, I can simply call the Async service method on the client using the appropriate async, Task, and await keywords accordingly.

Comment: @sagesky36: The main point of my answer is that you have *two* independent locations where you can choose to use `async`: client and server. If you want to make the client responsive, then use `async` on the client. If you want to make the server scalable, then use `async` on the server. Those are two completely separate decisions.

Comment: @StephenCleary what changes things between clustered vs non-clustered sql that you imply that async really benefits consumptions of clusters

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: Generally speaking, a single ASP.NET server can handle more simultaneous requests than a single SQL server. A cluster scales the SQL server part, possibly to the point where a single ASP.NET server cannot keep them all busy.

Comment: @StephenCleary so really the only reason to use async sql calls is if you expect to exceed the capacity of the database? as the async calls are better suited to waiting for a response from the database?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: That's the primary reason (from an ASP.NET app). The core benefit of async on the server side is scalability (of your ASP.NET app) - if a single SQL server would limit your scalability anyway, then there's no use spending time *switching* to async. But if you're developing from scratch it makes sense to use async from the get-go.

Comment: For discussion's sake I'm under console / service but this is pretty much the only thing i could find on the internet about the merit of sql async. My specific scenario is a gigantic cache prime then minimal IO